# Should I use Drupal with Nginx or Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, nginx, drupal, cms

I'm currently running my own built server, where I host my own coded website, as well as websites I have built for local businesses. Currently it's running Ubuntu server edition, with Nginx. I already have the virtual hosts configured to correctly serve the appropriate site according to which domain name is redirecting to my IP.

I'm working on a new project, for a local print newspaper, asking me to build an online site for them. I've done research, and I think that Drupal is the best CMS to use in this project. However, after looking into setting up Drupal/Nginx, it seems Nginx doesn't play nicely with PHP/Drupal. It'll require some extremely specific host file configurations, and I'm concerned about breaking my live sites in the process of setting up.

(1) Should I convert the web server from Nginx to Apache, which from what I can find plays very nicely with Drupal?

(2) Should I choose a different CMS than Drupal which will play nicely with Nginx?

(3) Can I set up Apache alongside Nginx, and allow my static pages to serve through Nginx, and my CMS-dependant sites to serve through Apache/Drupal?

(4) Is there some fourth option I'm not thinking of?

Comment: Why wouldn't nginx play nice with Drupal? It works fine for me...

Comment: @MichaelHampton If you could point me to a resource explaining how to set up Drupal on Nginx, without copy/pasting someone's conf file, that would be great. Otherwise, I'm still trying to find information about how to do this.

Comment: There are [many, many such resources out there](https://search.disconnect.me/searchTerms/serp?search=73f9e601-de24-461c-9fff-f42a7cfecfd7).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should choose whichever webserver you and the other people responsible for administering the system have the most comfort with.  I've run Drupal sites on nginx without a problem, so wherever you're reading that "Nginx doesn't play nicely with PHP/Drupal" is categorically incorrect.

Comment: The system is entirely self contained. There aren't any other people responsible for administering the system. Just me. Also, to elaborate on my comment 'Nginx doesn't play nicely with PHP/Drupal', I have scanned the Drupal site itself, as well as done several different Google searches. Each time, I can only come up with the result of a long discussion thread where one particular user wrote a specific conf file that he recommends to copy/paste. This user's suggestion won't work for me because i'm concerned it will break my current virtual host config.

Comment: If you could point me to a resource explaining how to set up Drupal on Nginx, without copy/pasting someone's conf file, that would be great. Otherwise, I'm still trying to find information about how to do this.